# Parallel Calling of Function for Non-linear Solving

Tags: python, performance

The end goal of my program is to use a non-linear solver to fit a set of parameters to my data set. I pull the data set from a database into a list `sprays`, then instantiate a list of `Strip` objects which parse that data for further processing.

```
strips = [Strip(spray) for spray in sprays]
```

`Spray.cool(hw, ha, coef, units)` is a class function which returns a 2-tuple `(err1, err2)` of errors. My goal is to minimize the mean-square error of this call for the entire data set. The total list of errors is generated by the following function:

```
def search(h):
    errors = []
    for strip in strips:
        errors += strip.cool(h[0], h[1], list(h[2:]), units)
    return errors
```

I have a preset parameter `units` which is a list of 6 floats.

**I have a few parameters I wish to fit:**
`hw` and `ha` are both floats.
`coef` is a list of six floats which will affect their corresponding elements in `units`.

I fit these parameters through the following function call from `scipy.optimize`

```
leastsq(search, (hw, ha, *coef))
```

Each individual call of `Strip.cool` takes ~10ms to execute, which is plenty fast for applications I am looking into. However, `strips` contains 1000s of elements, each calling `Strip.cool`, which adds up. It's bearable for a single call of `search`, but `leastsq` calls `search` numerous times to converge on a solution which adds up to hours of computation.

**How can improve the performance of this program?**
Ideally, I would make a change to `search` which would allow all elements of `strips` to call `cool` at once, in a sort of parallel call that I think I see in `numpy` array operations a lot. Also possible would be to change my approach to a non-linear fit, either by using a different solver or different method entirely (one that doesn't require calling `cool` for every instance in `strips` every iteration). I would prefer to steer away from editing `cool`, as I feel it is fairly optimized and a small increase in performance there will not greatly improve the overall performance (again, calling `cool` millions of times), but I have included it for the curious souls.

**What I have tried:**
`threading` and `multiprocessing` both require a bit of overhead to spin up a new routine. This overhead is greater than the execution time for a single call, and from what I've found using these methods results in a call to `search` actually taking longer.
`map` looked promising at first, as I hope that there was some parallel processing trickery going on under the hood. By defining

```
def run_strip(strip, *args):
    return strip.cool(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3])
```

a call of `map(lambda s: run_strip(s, h[0], h[1], list(h[2:]), units), strips)` produces the same results, but unfortunately with comparable processing time.

**Function definition**

```
def cool(self, hw, ha, coef, units): 

    bw = 2 * self.dy / self.k * hw
    ba = 2 * self.dy / self.k * ha

    atemp = 70

    Uwt = np.zeros_like(self.Matrix)
    Uwb = np.zeros_like(self.Matrix)
    Uwt[1,0] = Uwb[-2,-1] = self.alpha * bw * self.wtemp
    Uwt[1,1] = Uwb[-2,-2] = -self.alpha * bw

    Uat = np.zeros_like(self.Matrix)
    Uab = np.zeros_like(self.Matrix)
    Uat[1,0] = Uab[-2,-1] = self.alpha * ba * atemp
    Uat[1,1] = Uab[-2,-2] = -self.alpha * ba

    temperature = np.ones((int(self.y / self.dy) + 1)) * self.ftemp
    temps = np.empty((len(self.iterations), int(self.y / self.dy) + 1))

    for n, i, t, b in zip(range(len(rot.RegionLengths)), self.iterations, self.topSprays, self.botSprays):
        if t == 1:
            tunit = rot.TopSprayRegionUnits[n] * coef[:3][units[:3].index(tunit)]
            Ut = Uwt * tunit
        else:
            tunit = 1
            Ut = Uat
        if b == 1:
            bunit = rot.BottomSprayRegionUnits[n] * coef[3:][units[3:].index(bunit)]
            Ub = Uwb * bunit
        else:
            bunit = 1
            Ub = Uab

        temperature = np.matmul(np.linalg.matrix_power(self.Matrix+Ut+Ub, i), np.pad(temperature, (1, 1), 'constant', constant_values=((1,1),)))[1:-1]
        temps[n] = np.reshape(temperature, (1,-1))

    return temperature[0] - self.ctemp
```

Personal note:
Sorry for the problems with posing this question. The balance between too much detail and too much abstraction can be difficult. Hopefully this provides enough information now to point towards a solution.

Comment: I think this code is too general to be reviewed. We require concrete code with sufficient context to understand it. Otherwise the review would consist entirely of "Use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).".

Comment: @Graipher What seems too general about it? `Foo` is an object which has a function `dofoo` that takes several parameters. In this case `dofoo` returns a number. `func` returns the results of `dofoo` for all `Foo` instances in `foos`.

Comment: Using `foo` and `bar` is the epitome of stub code. And we dont review stub code on CR.

Comment: Edited to be less general.

Comment: Groger, to clarify @konijn's statement, it's not that your code looks too vague, it's that the purpose of Code Review is to review the quality, performance, etc. of actual, working code. It's supposed to be the exact code you're running because we're here to critique things like style, function layout, documentation, etc. If you don't know how to accomplish something or your code doesn't work the way you want it to, that's what Stack Overflow is for. I've flagged your question to request that the moderators migrate it there.

Comment: @Groger, when you saying "*perhaps calling in parallel*" - you'd need to understand that all your options are limited to `threading` or `multiprocessing` or `asyncio`. No need to invent/seek something "unearthly"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I second your remark, but would clarify that ```asyncio``` does not technically run code *in parallel*, it allows multiple pieces of code to trade off running in the same thread when one of them is waiting on I/O, a system call, or something else that isn't directly running Python code.

Comment: Another point is you saying "Each call of cool takes ~10 ms, which is pretty fast and cannot be further optimized". That might be true, but is not necessarily so. Supplying the actual method would allow us to check it and determine it ourselves. Maybe there is some way to do it better in `numpy`/`pandas`, although it might only be worth copying data if you do the whole process many times. Something else we don't know without seeing how the code is actually used.

Comment: @Graipher added code for the function.

Answer (score -2):

As @Graipher says: Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

You say

> Each call of dofoo takes ~10 ms, which is pretty fast and cannot be further optimized

which implies that your function is CPU bound, or at least that you're not spending the entire time waiting on disk or network I/O... if so, use asyncronous programming like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) or just regular old threads (the overhead would be small compared to your 10ms function). [If you read up on the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), you'll find that the Python interpreter is itself not thread-safe (and for good reasons, there are several great talks, articles, and projects that explore the costs of removing this global lock), hence why you need multiple processes to get proper parallelism.

That said, this is a really common problem and easily handled. The most obvious solution is [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html), which would make your code look like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def run_strip(strip, *args):
    return strip.cool(args)

def all_the_strips(x, y):
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        z = pool.starmap(run_strip, [(strip, x, y, a, b) for strip in strips])
    return [x for lst in z for x in lst]
```

There are more complicated ways of accomplishing the same task (e.g. setting up a `mp.Queue` and launching your own processes to consume it) if this solution doesn't fit your need.

Comment: This actually ends up being slower than my original code, likely due to the additional  overhead required to set this up.

Comment: @Groger how many CPU cores do you have? And is your code CPU-bound, or limited by something else (network, disk, etc.)?

Comment: 2 cores. The actual code crunching doesn't require any network communciation, memory is fine, CPU usage is pretty normal.